# Allure Reports Team City plugin causing builds to just hang on build step that runs tests

Tags: selenium, teamcity, allure

I'm trying to get allure reporting working as part of an NUnit project in C# using Selenium WebDriver. Following the documentation for installing allure seems to work fine on a local machine but I'm trying to get the Team City plugin to also work this the project. I've uploaded the allure team city plugin and added a build step that will generate a report even if the build fails or is stopped. The project has all the required allure nunit tags added and again this generates results locally that a report can be generated from. However, when running tests from Team City the build hangs and does not even begin to run tests. At the step that it should start running tests it just sits there. The Team City build logs do not show anything wrong. I'm using NUnit 3.6, Team City 2018.1, allure 2,7, allure team city plugin 2.9.

Does anyone have any experience with allure reporting? The documentation is a little out of date but I've done as much as I can with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is allowed, answering your own question, but in light of little on the ground of existing responses given the Allure developers actually suggest posting to this site as opposed to posting to their own Git hub site, I find it rather frustrating that there has been little response.

Anyway, having spent further hours looking into this I believe that the hanging of the builds is purely down to the allure-config.json file and the path to the allure-results setting within it. Any attempt to change that setting from its default appears to instantly cause the TC builds containing Allure Reports to hang. 
hopefully this may help others having similar issues in future.